# Can't connect to twitter using Spring Social : error=provider

Tags: java, spring, twitter, oauth, spring-social

I'm trying to get a twitter connection using Spring social. 
To do so, I followed the documentation and wrote this file :

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {

    @Value("${facebook.clientId}")
    private String facebookClientId;
    @Value("${facebook.clientSecret}")
    private String facebookClientSecret;

    @Value("${twitter.consumerKey}")
    private String twitterConsumerKey;
    @Value("${twitter.consumerSecret}")
    private String twitterConsumerSecret;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * When a new provider is added to the app, register its
     * {@link ConnectionFactory} here.
     * 
     * @see FacebookConnectionFactory
     */
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                facebookClientId, facebookClientSecret));
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                twitterConsumerKey, twitterConsumerSecret));
        return registry;
    }

    /**
     * Singleton data access object providing access to connections across all
     * users.
     */
    @Bean
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
                dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
        repository.setConnectionSignUp(new SimpleConnectionSignUp());
        return repository;
    }

    /**
     * Request-scoped data access object providing access to the current user's
     * connections.
     */
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
        User user = SecurityContext.getCurrentUser();
        return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(
                user.getId());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(){
        return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator(), connectionRepository());
    }

    /**
     * A proxy to a request-scoped object representing the current user's
     * primary Facebook account.
     * 
     * @throws NotConnectedException
     *             if the user is not connected to facebook.
     */
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Facebook facebook() {
        return connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class)
                .getApi();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Twitter twitter() {
        Connection<Twitter> connection = connectionRepository()
                .findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        Twitter twitter = connection != null ? connection.getApi()
                : new TwitterTemplate();
        return twitter;
    }
}
```

This code operates fine with facebook but gets me a provider=error with twitter. All keys are correct (the Twitter key work fine with Twitter4j). 
When I try to get a connection, the application sends me to twitter and then sends me back with the "error=provider" in the address.